# Can we load text file separated by :: into hive table?

Tags: hive

Is there a way to load a simple text file where fields are separated by "::" into hive table other than replacing those "::" with "," and then load it? 
 Replacing the "::" with "," is quicker when the text file is small but what if contains millions of records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating Hive table using **Regex serde**

**Example:**

i had file with below text in it.

```
i::90
w::99
```

***Create Hive table:***

```
hive> create external table default.i
(Id STRING,
Name STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex' = '(.*?)::(.*)')
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

***Select from Hive table:***

```
hive> select * from i;
+-------+---------+--+
| i.id  | i.name  |
+-------+---------+--+
| i     | 90      |
| w     | 99      |
+-------+---------+--+
```

In case if you want to **skip the header** then use below syntax:

```
hive> create external table default.i
(Id STRING,
Name STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex' = '(.*?)::(.*)')
STORED AS TEXTFILE
tblproperties ('skip.header.line.count'='1');
```

> ***UPDATE:***

Check is there any `older files` in your **table location**.if some files are there then delete them`(if you don't want them)`.

1.Create Hive table as:

```
create external table <db_name>.<table_name>
(col1 STRING,
col2 STRING,
col3 string,
col4 string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.RegexSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex' = '(.*?)::(.*?)::(.*?)::(.*)')
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

2.Then run:

```
load data local inpath 'Source path' overwrite into table 'Destination table'
```

Comment: It gives me error ED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.regexserde

Comment: @vicky, `regexserde` is case sensitive use this `RegexSerDe`. Try to create hive table again.

Comment: Ok, I did that. But this time my table got created but when I load the data and query the table it returns null for all fields which is basically the same I was getting earlier

Comment: @vicky,what do u mean by **load the data?**,Create an external table and copy the **file into the table location**..
Make sure your `regex` is correct and able to `capture the groups` correctly..
if you are still having issues Update the question with `some sample data`..!!

Comment: loading the data means  ( load data local inpath 'Source path' overwrite into table 'Destination table')  and sample data looks like this     
(1::914::3::978301968
1::3408::4::978300275
1::2355::5::978824291
1::1197::3::978302268
1::1287::5::978302039
1::2804::5::978300719
1::594::4::978302268
1::919::4::978301368
1::595::5::978824268)

Comment: @vicky,Not able to reproduce the same exact issue.. As i tried to recreate your scenario and **updated the original answer** (take a look into the answer).